# Train/Test/Validation stratified Set Splitting in Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe in python that looks like this (but is more extended).

[image]

I want to split the data set into three sets: train (70%), test (10%) and validate (20%). Because there are some classes that have little objects, I want to also split them stratified. Is there a way (using scikit) to split them stratified in three sets?

This [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/train-test-validation-set-splitting-in-sklearn) shows how to do it without the stratify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) stratified twice:

```py
non_validate_X, validate_X, non_validate_y, validate_y = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2)
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(non_validate_X, non_validate_y,stratify=non_validate_y, test_size=1./8)
```

I use a split of 1./8 in the second one because 1./8 = 10%/(70% + 10%); the fraction of test in your train+test.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't the non_validate_y and the validate_X switch? I get an error othewise

Comment: Correct, will update later!